# Recover key in HMAC-SHA256 message authentication

Tags: password-cracking, hmac, sha256

I am working on a demonstration of cookie security, where some important data is passed to the client along with a HMAC-SHA256 digest to prevent modification of the data. I would like to be able to show that using a weak key makes this easy to crack.

To generate the hash and data, here is a simple python script:

```
import hmac
from hashlib import sha256

message = "This is a long message that might be a little too long"
mkey = "password"
digest = hmac.new(mkey, message, sha256)
print(digest.hexdigest())
print(message.encode('hex'))
```

It outputs this data:

```
e3762ae7f3bc6c9f8906e5f1f2cd19e80d3ebd281bdd31119a66adaef33d3b3c
546869732069732061206c6f6e67206d6573736167652074686174206d696768742062652061206c6974746c6520746f6f206c6f6e67
```

Is there any tool that can help me efficiently crack the key? I could not find a way to do it in hashcat.

I could roll my own dictionary attack, but would rather use something off the shelf if it exists.

Comment: why can't an attacker replace the hmac passed with the replaced payload?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out [John the Ripper](https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper) can crack the HMAC digest (when built from bleeding branch at least), which is great. I just hadn't looked hard enough.

Comment: That answer is not quite the quality we want on this site. If you include information explaining how to do it, the answer would be much better.

Comment: JTR seems to be only able to do pbkdf2-hmac-sha256, or am I overlooking something? I got it to work in hashcat but not in jtr.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to protect the message then you have a serious problem, because it can be easily decoded with:

```
crypto = "546869732069732061206c6f6e67206d6573736167652074686174206d696768742062652061206c6974746c6520746f6f206c6f6e67"
print crypto
print crypto.decode('hex')
```

But since you've asked to retrieve the password via dictionary attack, I made a script that decodes the hex to plaintext which is then used as a salt in HMAC along with passwords in dictionary and SHA256 to produce hashes(mimicking the original HMAC function) which are then compared to the targeted hash string:

```
import hmac
from hashlib import sha256

hashd = 'e3762ae7f3bc6c9f8906e5f1f2cd19e80d3ebd281bdd31119a66adaef33d3b3c'
crypto = '546869732069732061206c6f6e67206d6573736167652074686174206d696768742062652061206c6974746c6520746f6f206c6f6e67'
decrypto = crypto.decode('hex')
keys = open('dictionary.txt').read().split() # Specifiy the path to the dictionary file

def mykey():
   for i in keys:
     digest=hmac.new(i, decrypto, sha256)
     digest.hexdigest()

     if digest.hexdigest()==hashd:
        print 'password:', i
        break

if mykey():
   print mykey()
```

So if the password is in the dictionary, it will print it out. Tested in python 2.7. Also note that the words have to be one per line in the dictionary for this to work properly.

**EDIT:** Here is a more flashy version, in case you need it for presentation:

```
import hmac
from hashlib import sha256
from datetime import datetime
startTime = datetime.now()

hashd = raw_input('SHA256: ')
crypto = raw_input('HEX: ')
decrypto = crypto.decode('hex')
keys = open('dictionary').read().split() # Specifiy the path to the dictionary file

def mykey():
   for i in keys:
      digest=hmac.new(i, decrypto, sha256)
      print digest.hexdigest(), '-', i

      if digest.hexdigest()==hashd:
         print 'Password found:', i
         break
   else:
      print 'Password not in the dictionary.'

if mykey():
   print mykey()

print 'Time Elapsed:', datetime.now() - startTime
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks pretty good. I was hoping for something tuned specifically for cracking, turns out John can do it.

Comment: Np, I'm glad you found a solution with JTR. I've also updated my script to look a bit more professional, just in case someone needs it the future :-)

Comment: Why are you calling `mykey` twice? And why are you using its return value even though it doesn't actually return anything?